# Java Reverse String Recursively Returns Empty

Tags: java, recursion

````
```
    String res = "";
    Solution.reverse("hellowolrd", res);
    System.out.println(res);
````

```
    public static void reverse(String str, String result) {
            if(str.length()==0) return; 
            result += str.charAt(str.length()-1); 
            reverse(str.substring(0,str.length()-1),result); 
        }
```

Why the res variable is empty when I print it out after calling reverse()

Comment: method is not returning anything and parameters are pass-by-value (in short, changing `result` inside the method does not change the corresponding variable on the calling method; `String` is immutable, but you could use a `StringBuilder` instead - or just return the result of concatenation)

Comment: Strings are immutable.  you need to write this as a function and return the string

Answer (score 0):

Because `result` is a copy of the `res` you are passing onto the `reverse` method. Your original `res` stays the same.

One thing  you could do is to use a `StringBuilder` which will modify the underlying storage.

```
    public static void reverse(String str, StringBuilder result) {
        if(str.length()==0) return; 
        result.append( str.charAt(str.length()-1) );
        reverse(str.substring(0,str.length()-1),result); 
    }
```

Comment: Is not the String class is a Reference Type ? How can it be copied like primitive int